# How to troubleshoot my "too many open files" error on Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets

I'm having some trouble with a program I wrote for Linux (some kind of a server), I'm getting the infamous "Too many open files" error.

Up until now I have thought it is a matter of sockets, but, after more searching it seemed that threads are "files" too in the eyes of Linux.

So, is it right that sockets and/or threads require file descriptors as well?

Comment: Linux is a unix derivative, and the overall guiding mantra for Unix systems from day 1 is "everything is a file". pretty much anything that has an "open()"-type call is going to return a file handle of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a typical UNIX or UNIX-like system, the following are represented by a file descriptor and are treated from the user perspective as such (in terms of the functions you can use):
files, pipes, sockets (UNIX and network sockets alike), character devices, block devices.

Threads and processes are NOT identified as files, neither from a user point of view, nor in the kernel.

The problem is that in some systems, the minimum limitations are too low; so to set a system-wide (actually a user- or group-wide) change to the upper limit a process can open; modify the file `/etc/security/limits.conf`
and add the following line:
user_name (soft | hard) nofile (some_number_that_specifies_the_limit)

Of course, as has been mentioned already, this can be done in code using the function to set the maximum number of files opened by the calling process [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)

Please note that setting hard limit on any resource requires root access while setting a soft limit using the command ulimit or a function in code typically doesn't up to the allowed hard-limit.

Concerning your comment about threads:
Creating too many threads can cause a failure because you are limited with amount of threads or processes you can spawn, you'll see that for example `fork` fails with setting errno to `EAGAIN` if it cannot get a new process; like in file-limit, this can be changed using `setrlimit` function.

Note however that creating too many threads has nothing to do with the error "too many open files".

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are definitely represented with file handles. I've never heard anyone cite that threads are backed by file handles, although it wouldn't surprise me.

In any case...

Use the [ulimit](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ulimit/) command with the -n option from the shell before launching your program. That will allow you to raise the max file limit.  You can also look at using the [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) function to be invoked from your code to do the same thing.

You didn't go into too many details, but is it possible you are hitting the too many files limit because your code is not actually closing the socket and thread handles when you done using them?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, so threads cannot create "too many open files" error ? is this only a Socket oriented error ?